# Percentage discount for X number of item options in Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob

I have products in a channel that each have a CartThrob Price Modifier to choose a size.

What I would like to do is to give a customer 10% off if they buy more than 10 of any of those options in the Price Modifier.

I was wondering if it's possible to have a discount like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if its possible with any existing feature of CartThrob, It might be implement with discount plugin.

You can take a reference for developing discount plugin from here : http://cartthrob.com/docs/developers/discount_plugins/index.html